# Why is my input box not showing in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When my code asks for an input using `input()`, the input box doesn't show in the output box **sometimes**. It's always the second input that doesn't show, and I'm not sure if this is a processing error and if it needs some time to load, but below is my code and a screenshot of the output box.

```
#--------Chess--------#

#import
from IPython.display import clear_output 

#chessboard
board = [["♜", "♞", "♝", "♛", "♚", "♝", "♞", "♜"],
        ["♟", "♟", "♟", "♟", "♟", "♟", "♟", "♟"],
        ["□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□"],
        ["□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□"],
        ["□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□"],
        ["□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□ ", "□"],
        ["♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙"],
        ["♖", "♘", "♗", "♕", "♔", "♗", "♘", "♖"]]

#other variables
gameEnded = False

#functions
def printRank(rank):
  rank -= 1
  print("|  |" + board[rank][0] + " " + board[rank][1] + " " + board[rank][2] + " " + board[rank][3] + " " + board[rank][4] + " " + board[rank][5] + " " + board[rank][6] + " " + board[rank][7] + "|  |")

def printboard():
    printRank(1)
    printRank(2)
    printRank(3)
    printRank(4)
    printRank(5)
    printRank(6)
    printRank(7)
    printRank(8)

def posInAlphabet(letter):
  pos = ord(letter) - 96
  return pos

#gameLoop
while gameEnded == False:
    #PIECE TO MOVE
    #refresh board
    clear_output()
    printboard()

    #take input for piece to move
    print("Which piece to move? (e.g a1)")
    pieceToMove = input()

    #get actual position of that piece
    pieceX = 8 - int(pieceToMove[1])
    pieceY = int(posInAlphabet(pieceToMove[0])) - 1

    print(pieceX)
    print(pieceY)

    #get the type of that piece
    pieceType = board[pieceX][pieceY]

    #replace that piece with a blank space
    board[pieceX][pieceY] = " □"

    #MOVE PIECE
    #refresh board
    clear_output()
    printboard()
    
    #take input for plate to move the piece to
    print("Where to move piece to? (e.g b2) type 'back' to go back")
    movePosition = input() #THIS IS THE LINE THE ERROR OCCURS IN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    if movePosition == "back":
      board[pieceX][pieceY] = pieceType
      continue 

    #get actual position to move the piece to
    destX = 8 - int(movePosition[1])
    destY = int(posInAlphabet(movePosition[0])) - 1

    #replace that space with the piece to move
    board[destX][destY] = pieceType
```

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnr8.png)

I've tried adding a prompt in as seen below:

`input("Where do you want to move the piece to?")`

as that seems to have worked for some other people online, but it doesn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do something similar and wanted to clear output to display the new board, however, for some reason, using the clear_output() caused the input box to not be displayed sometimes.

instead, if you use:

```
from google.colab import output
output.clear() # where you need to clear output
```

the input box does not disappear. I hope this helps.